# Как работает SqlBulkCopy в .NET "за кулисами"?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Интереса ради заглянул в [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlBulkCopy.cs), чтобы понять как представление данных в памяти пуляется на сервер, однако, что-то не нашел этого места.

Билдер команды нашел, но, вроде, в нем нет ничего сверхъестественного.

Нашел, где данные хранятся перед отправкой - независимо от того, что подается на вход, они копируются в массив, но самого интересного не нашел...

Comment: @i-one, оформите ответом ~ это я и хотел услышать со ссылками на методы, где это все происходит.

Answer (score 4):

Общение клиентских приложений с SqlServer происходит посредством протокола TDS (*Tabular Data Stream Protocol*), спецификацию которого можно найти [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx).

При bulk-загрузке клиент посылает серверу сообщение типа *Bulk Load* (раздел 2.2.1.5 спецификации):

> **2.2.1.5 Bulk Load**
>   ...
>   The client sends the **INSERT BULK** SQL statement and then sends a
>   COLMETADATA token that describes the raw data. Multiple rows of binary
>   data are then sent to the server.
>   ...

т.е. серверу передаются (последовательно)

- `INSERT BULK` команда (специальная разновидность [INSERT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql), не путать с `BULK INSERT`)
- метаданные столбцов передаваемых данных
- собственно сами строки данных

Если сообщение длинное (например, текст команды длинный, или данных много, что типично для bulk-загрузки), то оно передаётся несколькими пакетами.

Для осуществления взаимодействия посредством TDS-протокола *SqlBulkCopy* использует вспомогательный класс *[TdsParser](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs)*. Вообще *TdsParser* (вместе с *[TdsParserStateObject](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs)*) является одним из краеугольных классов во внутренней инфраструктуре *System.Data.SqlClient* (и используется также такими классами как, например, *SqlCommand*, *SqlDataReader*, *SqlConnection*).

Последовательность от вызова метода *WriteToServer* (*WriteToServerAsync*) до отправки данных на сервер примерно такая:

```
WriteToServer
  WriteRowSourceToServerAsync
    WriteToServerInternalAsync
      ReadFromRowSourceAsync
      WriteToServerInternalRestAsync
        CreateAndExecuteInitialQueryAsync
          CreateInitialQuery
      WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync
        AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand
        CopyBatchesAsync
          SubmitUpdateBulkCommand
          CopyBatchesAsyncContinued
            WriteMetaData
            CopyRowsAsync
              CopyColumnsAsync
                ReadWriteColumnValueAsync
                  GetValueFromSourceRow
                    TdsParser.WriteBulkCopyValue
```

Из этого наиболее интересно следующее.

Метод *[CreateInitialQuery](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#545e0701deaee989)* формирует команду

```
SET FMTONLY ON
select * from [TableName]
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

которая используется для получения информации о столбцах целевой таблицы.

Метод *[AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#e5fb9da82448b1d3)* формирует `INSERT BULK` команду наподобие, например, такой

```
insert bulk [TableName] ([Id] int) with (TABLOCK)
```

Метод *[SubmitUpdateBulkCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#e117e60d7c7f5552)* передаёт сформированный текст команды на сервер.

Метод *[WriteMetaData](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#8db689ce1ef35c8d)* передаёт метаданные столбцов. В этом методе, что интересно, перед передачей метаданных есть строка кода

```cs
_stateObj._outputMessageType = TdsEnums.MT_BULK;
```

(префикс `MT_` означает *message type*). Это значит, что передача *Bulk load* сообщения инициируется здесь, а не с отправки команды `INSERT BULK` несколько ранее в методе *[SubmitUpdateBulkCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#e117e60d7c7f5552)*. Если вернуться ненадолго в этот метод, то можно найти там вызов *[TdsExecuteSQLBatch](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs.html#a160614ab3bee307)*, проследовав внутрь которого, можно обнаружить строку кода

```cs
stateObj._outputMessageType = TdsEnums.MT_SQL;
```

т.е. текст команды посылается отдельным сообщением.

Это несколько неожиданно, т.к. читая раздел 2.2.1.5 спецификации сложилось впечатление, что и текст команды также должен быть частью *Bulk load* сообщения. Впрочем, в разделе 2.2.6.1 спецификации

> **2.2.6.1 Bulk Load BCP**
>   ...
>   This message sent to the server contains bulk data to be inserted. The
>   client MUST have previously notified the server where this data is to
>   be inserted. For more information about the INSERT BULK syntax, see
>   [MSDN-INSERT].
>   ...

поясняется (недостаточно явно, на мой взгляд), что *Bulk load* сообщение содержит данные для вставки, а перед его отправкой серверу нужно сообщить куда вставлять данные.

Таким образом, bulk-загрузка происходит посредством отправки двух сообщений серверу:

1. `INSERT BULK` команда (*куда* вставляем)
2. метаданные столбцов данных + строки данных (*что* вставляем)

Следуем дальше.

Метод *[CopyRowsAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#4fbaa0f95a48bd60)* отвечает за передачу строк данных.

Внутри *[ReadWriteColumnValueAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs.html#3cc4cdca3b702ef5)* происходит вызов метода *[WriteBulkCopyValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs.html#1391935b05d06d33)* класса *TdsParser*.

Внутри метода *[WriteBulkCopyValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs.html#1391935b05d06d33)* последовательность вызовов примерно следующая

```
TdsParser.WriteBulkCopyValue
  TdsParser.WriteValue/WriteSqlValue/WriteShort/WriteInt/WriteLong/WriteDouble/...
    TdsParserStateObject.WriteByte/WriteByteArray
      TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket
        TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni
          TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket
            SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIWritePacket
```

Логика разнообразных вызовов, происходящих внутри *[WriteBulkCopyValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs.html#1391935b05d06d33)*, заключается в основном в том, что данные (в байтовом представлении) пишутся в буфер, пока он не полон. Когда же буфер (будущий TDS-пакет) заполнился (TDS-пакет готов), происходит его отправка на сервер (метод *[SNIWritePacket](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs.html#f71ef034502cfa6a)*).

Внутри *[SNIWritePacket](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs.html#f71ef034502cfa6a)* вызов метода *SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIWritePacket* - это обращение ко внешней библиотеке *sni.dll*, которая обеспечивает взаимодействие с транспортным уровнем (*Shared Memory*, *Named Pipes*, *TCP*).

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy использует datatable, IDataReader или DataRow[] в качестве источника данных. Обратите внимание на [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.7.2) если хотите больше подробностей. А также на [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)), там рассматриватся BCP, но информация о BulkCopy также представлена.